# How is Yayoi able to break a window with a fly kick, jump several meters, and hit a ghost if she's just a child with no physical superpowers?

Tags: dark-gathering

Yayoi is just a 9-10 years old genius with an IQ of 160. She uses several tools to fight ghosts, but supposedly, she doesnt have physical superpowers.

In episode 24 of the anime, she and other students felt unconscious, and they are either in a dream or in another dimension. There, she's able to break a window with a fly kick, jump several meters, and hit a ghost with a kind of baseball bat prepared specially to fight ghosts, I assume. How was she able to do that? Is because she was in a sort of dream? Does she have some supernatural physical skills aside of her high IQ and supernatural power to see ghosts?